# C++ проверка типа данных

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, типы-данных

Писав функцию с переменным списком параметров различного типа **[** Например :  **FSum(2, 3.5, 4, "a", 32, string("abc") )** **]**, которая  должна суммировать значение только int типа , наткнулся на проблему с проверкой типа данных. Пробовал использовать typeid но почему-то не всегда корректно работает со string. Можно ли это как-то исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
int FSum(T t) {

    if (typeid(t) == typeid(int)) 
        return t;

    else return 0;
}

template <typename T, typename ... TSet>
int FSum(T t, TSet...ts) {

    if (typeid(t) == typeid(int)) {

        if (sizeof...(TSet) == 1) 
            return t;

        return t + FSum(ts...);

    }

    else return FSum(ts...);

}


int main() {

    string S("abs");

    //cout << "FSum( ) = " << FSum(21.4, 3.4, 40,'d',1.2,100,"ss") << endl; //не компилирует
    cout << "FSum( ) = " << FSum(21.4, 3.4, 40,'d',1.2,100) << endl; //компилирует


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Покажите свой код, будем фиксить.

Comment: Лучше добавить в сам вопрос (кнопка [edit]).

Comment: так если нужны только int, то зачем позволять функции принимать что-то кроме int?

Comment: Задание такое (

Comment: теперь распишите, что значит "не всегда корректно работает со string"

Comment: Для проверки равенства типов лучше использовать `std::is_same` - это функция времени компиляции.

Comment: user78608670 string ( как и указатель на char) почему-то доходит до этапа return t в int FSum(T t){...}

Comment: А до куда он должен доходить по-вашему?

Comment: насколько я понимаю до else return 0

Comment: приведенный код никуда не доходит, так как он [не компилируется](https://godbolt.org/z/p2oWq3)

Comment: посмотрите первое error сообщение и ещё можете убрать из параметров вызова "ss" , т.к. именно "ss" привод к тому , что код не компилируется.

Answer (score 2):

С++17 может так вот:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename ... TSet> 
int FSum(T t, TSet...ts) 
{ 
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(t)>, int>) 
    {
        if (sizeof...(TSet) == 0) // Тут всё же 0 наверно?
            return t; 
        return t + FSum(ts...);
    } 
    else 
        return FSum(ts...);
 }
```

Хотя в том же С++17 можно вот такое провернуть (с fold-expression) в самом начале функции, и тогда не скомпилятся инстанцирования не с интами:

```cpp
static_assert(
    (std::is_same_v<TSet, int> && ...)
    "FSum should receive only integers"
);
```